# Test for Json output in postman console shows false but pass in Test tab

Tags: json, testing, arraylist, console, postman

Doing test for array properties list for users in postman console shows fail but tests tab shows pass.

```
var responseData =pm.response.json();
pm.test("Test for UserFound", function () 
{console.log(pm.expect(responseData.users[0].firstname) === ("test"));
```

});
Test tab shows Pass, but console shows false

Let me know if anything missing.
[image: consolepostman]

Comment: @danny pls answer to my other query .. need help for edited the question

Comment: Where have you got that syntax from? Are you just making things up and hope they work? `pm.expect(responseData.users[0].firstname).to.eql("test")` Is the syntax. I would suggest reading the Postman Docs and also learn the syntax of ChaiJS.

Comment: I made that syntax :) it works with test, but want to check on logs, it shows false there. Will look into ChaiJS. let me try to print that separately.

Comment: Something might to getting returned by it might not be doing what you think it is